# set textbox value in Reportviewer using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

i have a reportviewer containing a a textbox and tablix.
The tablix is populated using a datasource(which gets data using  a stored proc with 2 parameters from a query string).
How do i specify the value of the query strings as the value of my reportviewer textbox.
something like:
This ReportfFrom query String val1 to query String val 2.

markup:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" 
    CssClass="ReportAlignment" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
    InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" 
    WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="550px">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="TempEmpWageSummaryReport.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="LoadWageSummary" Name="DataSet1" />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="LoadWageSummary" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:stockerConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="procTempEmployeeWageSummaryReport" 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="startDate" QueryStringField="start" 
            Type="String" />
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="endDate" QueryStringField="end" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string start = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["start"]);
        string end = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["end"]);
        //this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "TempEmpWageSummaryReport.rdlc";
        string param0 = "GROUPED TEMPORARY EMPLOYEE WAGE SUMMARY REPORT FROM " + start + "to " + end;
        ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", param0);
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp });

        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

        //BindReport();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: your approach seems correct just create a parameter "ReportParameter1" in the report, if you haven't already created and bind it to your textbox, it should work

Answer (score 1):

If you save the report with the value desire in the textbox you can process through the xml in the report's definition to grab the value, however I wouldn't recommend this.
You're better off just having a textbox outside the report for this and just give that to the Query to fetch the data.

Other than the above, I'm almost certain that grabbing the value from the textbox in the report that the user has specified isn't possible, unless the report is saved and then you process through the report's definition and grab the value which is a pain if you don't know what you're doing.